# vs2015 ssdt : publish could not drop table from db (deleted from package)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am successful to add create a table in SSDT project and publish to DB. 
The Publish could not drop that table from database when it has been deleted from project.

[image]

Even 'Drop objects in terget but not in project' checked in project\Properties\Debug\Deployment options.

However, it is working when upgrading the database from the .dacpac (in review the upgrade plan).

[image]

Could not find 'Drop objects in terget but not in project' in project\My Advanced Publish Settings:

[image]

Any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in tab Drop of Publish\Advanced

[image]

Comment: If that doesn't do it, there is another setting in the list below: "Do not drop tables." Need to uncheck that as well.